# Facebook Request Dialog for mobile - filtering users

Tags: ios, facebook, dialog, request

I'm using request dialog in mobile app. Reading 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/
I've found that

> Note: the filters option is disabled on mobile dialogs and will not affect the set of users that appear in the dialog.

Unfortunately I need to show only friends with app installed in one dialog, and rest in the other. Is there any reasonable way to filter users like this while still using FB request dialog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a look at the Hackbook sample app, packaged with the SDK to show you how to do this, but in essence you have to create an API call to get, say users with the app installed and pass this to a parameter called "suggestions".

```
- (void)sendRequest:(NSArray *) targeted {
    NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               @"It's your turn, quit slacking.",  @"message",
                               nil];

    // Filter and only show targeted friends
    if (targeted != nil && [targeted count] > 0) {
        NSString *selectIDsStr = [targeted componentsJoinedByString:@","];
        [params setObject:selectIDsStr forKey:@"suggestions"];
    }

    [self.facebook dialog:@"apprequests"
                  andParams:params
                andDelegate:self];
}


- (void) sendToAppUsers {
    FBRequest *appUsersRequest = [[FBRequest alloc]
                                  initWithSession:FBSession.activeSession
                                  restMethod:@"friends.getAppUsers"
                                  parameters:nil
                                  HTTPMethod:@"GET"];
    FBRequestConnection *appUsersConnection = [[FBRequestConnection alloc] init];
    [appUsersConnection
     addRequest:appUsersRequest
     completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
         // Process the results
         NSMutableArray *friendsWithApp = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
         // Many results
         if ([result isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
             [friendsWithApp addObjectsFromArray:result];
         } else if ([result isKindOfClass:[NSDecimalNumber class]]) {
             [friendsWithApp addObject: [result stringValue]];
         }
         // User has friends that pass this filter
         if ([friendsWithApp count] > 0) {
             [self sendRequest:friendsWithApp];
         }
    }];
    [appUsersConnection start];
}
```